# Home entertainment only

Tags: amplifiers

We have a Lesley 760 which I use with my Carlovox accordeon. We also have a Kawai ES7 keyboard with no external speakers. I'm wondering if I can connect the ES7 to the Leslie and what I would need extra to do so. I am not knowledgeable in this field and I don't want to risk damaging the equipment. Thanks.
Arie.

Comment: How is the accordeon connected? What ports are used for outputs on the Kawai?

Answer (score 1):

Tim is correct in pointing out the lack of critical information in this post, but the usual method of connecting two or more instruments to an amplifier is to use a mixer, usually small and simple, between the instruments and the amplifier. This will allow either instrument to be played by itself or in combination with the other instrument. Most of the time, instruments are connected using 1/4 inch phone plugs and I'm making an assumption that the Leslie is using a footswitch pedal that has 1/4 inch phone jacks as inputs. If my assumption is incorrect then you'll probably need to find one of those also.

Comment: I am only trying to find out what is needed to connect the Kawai ES7 to that Leslie 760. Nothing to do with the accordéon, which is connected to the Leslie through a Leslie Combo Pre- Amp II. I do not intent to have the Kawai and accordeon hooked up to the Leslie  at the same time. Thanks. Arie.

Comment: @Arie Brienen- You have revealed to me that you have a leslie preamp, that's good. Now I need to know the kinds of outputs that are available on the keyboard. I should be able to provide an answer when I have that information. I don't expect you'll need a  mixer.

Comment: I took a picture of the back of the keyboard showing all those connections but now I can't figure out how to provide that here as an attachment. As I said this is not my expertise. Anyway it has two 1/4 inch outs - Left (Mono) and Right. There are also others for Midi etc. The Pre-Amp has two channels also using 1/4 inch jacks. I don't want to risk damaging anything. Would it be safe to simply run a cable from the keyboard out to the pre-amp channel one or two?

Comment: @Arie Brienen- That's correct, Plug into the left (Mono)  channel on the Kawai and plug the other end of the cable into the Leslie preamp. There should be no damage to any component. Good luck!

Comment: @ArieBrienen you can insert a pic by dragging it to the question typing window, or copy it and paste it in,